# Accessing Domino mails in asp.net/C3 without installing Lotus Notes Client

Tags: c#, asp.net, lotus-domino

I have a windows service written in .NET/C# which reads emails from a Domino mailbox. Currently I am using the Lotus Notes .NET Interop to achieve this. However for this the Lotus Notes Client needs to be installed on the server. I am trying to find a way in which I can achieve this without having to install the Lotus Client on the server. From whatever I have read, I did not find anything. 
Proposion N2N is an ADO.NET provider for Domino, but even that needs the client to be installed on the server.
Is there a solution available for this?

Answer (score 0):

In a word, no.

You don't need *all* of the Notes client (or Domino server) install to get to the data, but you do need a significant part of it (and an ID that has access). Even if you take nothing else into account at all, you'd need a "driver" that recognises and can read all of the various ODS (on-disk structure) versions your database might be in, and it has to be able to handle both stored MIME and Notes Rich Text composite data structures with LMBCS (Lotus Multibyte Character Strings). Neither of those tasks is trivial. Then there's the security to get around: most document data are not stored in the clear even if the database is not locally encrypted (which only prevents unauthorized access from within a Notes/Domino environment if the ID for which it has been encrypted has not been compromised) and the storage method is not published.

In other words, you'd need something that is most of Notes in order to read and/or write, and the easiest way to get most of Notes is to install Notes.